# Race question for curiosity purposes

Tags: nicknames

What is the name for someone that wants to be a different race. Like for example if I wanted to be black but I am white what would be the name for that.I saw a post like this and I didn't get a clear answer so I thought I would ask myself.

Comment: You thought you would ask yourself? :)

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange EL&U. My preference--and obviously not yours--is to use the word "color," not "race." There is one race: the human race. In other words, we're all of one race but of different colors and phsyiognomies. I'm just sayin' . . ..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the popular catch all [**self-identify**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Self-identify) which means:

> To believe or assert that one belongs to a certain group or class

(American Heritage Dictionary)

There is a person who "self-identifies" as black despite being of non-black descent. Wikipedia article on her is [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_Dolezal).

So you could say you "self-identify" as black. Alternatively, you could describe yourself simply as "envious" of features of a particular race (or culture).

Comment: If you reject the whole concept that humanity is divided into distinct races, then one way of drawing attention to what you regard as a fiction is to expose it to ridicule. If your skin is very dark, and your great grandparents all came from West Africa, self-identifying as Caucasian would be one way of doing that. Likewise if your skin is not dark and you are provably descended from a long line of Caucasians then you can self-identify as black to heap ridicule on the concept of race.